# How do I toggle my touchscreen with a keyboard shortcut, or from a script?

Tags: windows, script, touchscreen, device-manager, wmi

I want to press a keyboard shortcut to toggle my touchscreen state on/off. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this via the Windows Script Host, [via PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pnpdevice/enable-pnpdevice?view=win10-ps), or via [DevCon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon).

DevCon is an external download and PowerShell is slow, so I'll show the WScript method:

1. Create a text file named `ToggleTouchscreen.js` with the following contents:

   ```
   for (var e = new Enumerator(GetObject('winmgmts:\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2').ExecQuery(
       'SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE Caption = "HID-compliant touch screen"',
       null, 48)); !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
       var item = e.item();
       item[item.Status === 'OK' ? 'Disable' : 'Enable']();
   }
   ```
2. Place a shortcut to that file somewhere in your start menu, such as in your Start Menu Programs folder (that's `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`, where `%AppData%` is usually `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME`).
3. Go to the Properties of the shortcut, and in the *Shortcut* tab, under *Shortcut key*, enter the shortcut key that you'd like to use and press OK.

Troubleshooting:

For some reason, some other methods of disabling a device (such as via DevCon) seem to prevent it from being enabled with this method.
If for some reason the device is found correctly but toggling its state doesn't work, try first enabling the device manually in Device Manager (`devmgmt.msc`), and then toggling it via this script to disable it.

Comment: Really nice to see you find a solution, and posted it here! Please set the answer as solution to close the issue.

Comment: @davidbaumann: Will do as soon as it lets me... I can't accept my own answer for the next two days.