# I'd like to toggle my laptop's touch screen with shortcuts. found post but getting errors

Tags: windows, script, windows-11, touchscreen

[How do I toggle my touchscreen with a keyboard shortcut, or from a script?](https://superuser.com/questions/1405954/how-do-i-toggle-my-touchscreen-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-or-from-a-script/1405955#1405955?newreg=e00974508f8d4d44b1f5a1e0469d6773)

I found script someone wrote years ago and tried to use that script but getting errors. I followed instruction in above link.

Error image is as below

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZrDl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use PowerShell scripts for turning on or off the touch function.

To disable :

```
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like ‘*touch screen*’} | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

To enable :

```
Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$_.FriendlyName -like '*touch screen*'} | Enable-PnpDevice -Confirm:$false
```

You may create two PowerShell scripts as `.ps1` files containing these
commands, then create desktop icons to launch them as Administrator.
You may assign any shortcut keys to run the desktop icons.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How To Enable Or Disable Touchscreen On Windows](https://www.technewstoday.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-touchscreen-on-windows/).